# Flutter - Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have 2 streams in my codes the first one is to get the userid from friend list and the second stream is to use the list of ids to search for the userid's document in firebase.

```
Stream friendIDStream;
Stream friendNameStream;

Widget friendList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: friendNameStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FriendTile(
                      snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["username"]);
                },
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserFriend();
    getNameByID();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserFriend() async {
    Constant.currentId =
        await HelperFunctions.getUserIdSharedPreference(Constant.currentId);
    setState(() {
      firebaseMethods.getFriend(Constant.currentId).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          friendIDStream = value;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  getNameByID() {
    setState(() {
      firebaseMethods.getFriendName(friendIDStream).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          friendNameStream = value;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the firestore code.

```
  Future getFriend(String ownerid) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(ownerid)
        .collection("friends")
        .snapshots();
  }

  Future getFriendName(friendid) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(friendid)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I doesn't know why is this happening since I can display the list of ids. I had tried changing `docs` to `doc` but is also produce the same error.

Edit:

Added photos of my database structure.
[image: Path to get a user id from friend list.]

[image: Username with userid]

Comment: Show please `friendNameStream` code, how you get it

Comment: The code for the ```friendNameStream``` is in the ```getNameById()``` function.

Comment: What it looks like to me is that you are trying to use `QuerySnapshot` properties on a `DocumentSnapshot`. What you're returning from the `getFriendName` function is a DocumentSnapshot. So just remove the `.doc(friendid)` method from that function and it should return all of the docs.

Comment: @Unbreachable Tried it just now but return a query snapshot has no instance method 'call' error.

Comment: @RaymondChong Oh yes, also remove the `data()` from `snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["username"]);` and it should start working now.

Comment: @Unbreachable Actually your first answer works. It's just that I mixed my code with the other answers. The code works just fine without removing the ```data()``` from ```snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["username"]);```. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Unbreachable Your code works fine but it does not produce the result that I've wanted. Your code display all the username that is registered but not the username that is added.

Comment: @RaymondChong what do you mean by "added"? Is this part of your original question?

Comment: @Unbreachable What I wanted to display is the username that is in the ```friends``` collection. Inside the ```friends``` collection is the users that is added. And I only store the user's id in the ```friends``` collection.

Comment: @RaymondChong I am a bit confused. What you have stored in the `friends` collection is the `friendid` field, not the `username`. That is only in the `users` collection. So what do you mean by "What I wanted to display is the username that is in the friends collection." ?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is your function getFriendName is returning a documentsnapshot not a querysnapshot. SO replace your old code with this:-

```
Widget friendList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: friendNameStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FriendTile(
                      //snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["username"] old one
                        snapshot.data["username"]); //new one
                },
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I've tried it just now but still having the same error.

Comment: i have updated code pls try and there are other issues as well in your code so it would be better if you show your database structure(like the fields stored in the documents). So i can help you out.

Comment: I's tried it again and it still results in the same error but if I change the ```itemCount``` to 1 the error changes to 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'call'.